# Python Memory error using meshgrid

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, coordinates

I am importing geophysical data collected along profiles with the coordinates in UTM format. The data looks as follows

```
Easting Northing    Ch1 Ch2 Ch3 Ch4
315467.994  6801358.217 -11.82  -9.12   -6.21   -3.19
315467.995  6801358.204 -11.91  -9.12   -6.21   -2.89
315467.996  6801358.191 -11.82  -9.36   -5.85   -3.18
315467.997  6801358.178 -11.57  -9.11   -6.21   -2.89
315467.998  6801358.165 -11.33  -8.99   -5.85   -2.89
```

I bring the data in, check the limits, run my interpolation and it crashes with a memory error (in meshgrid I think).

Traceback (most recent call last):

> 316267 315388 6800805 6800790 -2462 4113
>   
>   File "C:PycharmProjects/testing/EM61 data plot.py", line 44, in 
>   Number of points in X and Y - 3516 60
>   
>     X,Y= np.meshgrid(East,North)
>   
>   File "\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\function_base.py", line 4679, in meshgrid
>   
>     output = [x.copy() for x in output]
>   
>   File "C:\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\function_base.py", line 4679, in 
>   
>     output = [x.copy() for x in output]
>   
> MemoryError

It runs OK on small files displaying a grid image with the data points plotted on top but once I get to bigger files it crashes. My files can have up to 250,000 lines of data and can be as large as 1000 x 50 points in the grid.

Example image:

[image: example image]

Is there some straightforward way of avoiding the memory error?

```
from tkinter import filedialog
from tkinter import *
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import mlab, cm
from matplotlib.mlab import griddata

root = Tk()
root.filename = filedialog.askopenfilename( filetypes = ( ("CSV files","*.csv"),("All files", "*.*")))

#Set up root window
root.title ("TestGUI") # the name of the window
root.geometry("400x300")

#Open a file
data = np.genfromtxt(root.filename, delimiter=',', skip_header=2) # Get data from file as list

#Extract data from data list
East = data[:,][:,0]
North = data[:,][:,1]
Ch1 = data[:,][:,2]
Ch2 = data[:,][:,3]
Ch3 = data[:,][:,4]
Ch4 = data[:,][:,5]

# Find the data limits
Maxx=int(max(East))
Minx=int(min(East))
Maxy=int(max(North))
Miny=int(min(North))

#Printing info for tracking program performance
print ("Number of points in file",len(East))
print (Maxx,Minx,Maxy,Miny,int(min(Ch1)),int(max(Ch1)))

#Generate grid
#Produce a list of x coordinates based on the max and min of the data spaced 1 metre apart

xi = np.linspace(Minx, Maxx, (Maxx-Minx))
yi = np.linspace(Miny, Maxy, (Maxy-Miny))

print ("Number of points in X and Y -",len(xi),len(yi))

X,Y= np.meshgrid(East,North)
Z1 = griddata(East, North, Ch1, xi, yi, interp='nn')
cmap = cm.get_cmap(name='rainbow', lut=None) # Change the colour scheme
plt.contourf(xi,yi,Z1,20,cmap=cmap) # Plot the filled contours
# plt.contour(xi,yi,Z1,20) Plots the contour lines on the colour plot
plt.colorbar()

# Plot the points on the grid
plt.scatter(East,North,label="scatter",color="k",s=1,marker="+")

plt.show()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: What is the purpose of the line `X,Y= np.meshgrid(East,North)`? It seems like `X` and `Y` are never being used in the script and also from the logic there is no need for them being calculated.

Comment: Good point. I'd stared at that for ages without noticing that meshgrid was itself a relict of something earlier that I was not using and that now the program was somewhow a combination of an imshow and contourf routine. If I take that out the program is incredibly slow but it does appear to run.